# SQL SERVER 2008:Find all objects in stored procedure not having (NOLOCK) statement

Tags: regex, sql-server-2008, wildcard

I have an SQLSERVER 2008 SP having more than 3000 lines of code. I have to find out all the objects (Tables/Views) in the SP which does not have WITH (NOLOCK) statement in it. Is there an easier way to find all such objects and add the WITH (NOLOCK) statement preferably using wildcard/regular expression from the SQLServer Management Studio?

Comment: Rather than do that, why not just set the transaction isolation level to [`READ UNCOMMITTED`](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ms173763.aspx) - if that behaviour is really what's required?

Comment: Client wants NOLOCK statement specifically for each object. So iam looking for a find and replace option in SQL Server Management Studio.

Comment: @papfan: Your client is clueless. They need educating. http://stackoverflow.com/a/2141802/27535 and the links in http://stackoverflow.com/a/3873302/27535